# Unity3D multidisplay shifts one display off

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I am trying to make simple multidisplay application in Unity3D. However, picture on one of displays is shifted down with gray space above it:
[image]

It is not look like camera fault, and I don't have any big gray objects in the composition:
[image]

I activated different "Target display" for both cameras and using simple code to activate additional display:

```
void Start()
{
    if (Display.displays.Length > 1)
        Display.displays[1].Activate();
    if (Display.displays.Length > 2)
        Display.displays[2].Activate();
    }
```

Anyone have a clue, where problem can be?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Viewport Rect of your cameras is set correctly (should be X0, Y0, W1, H1) at runtime. Maybe upon switching display they get messed up!?

Comment: Viewport Rect for both cameras set to X0, Y0, W1, H1 and now problem faced during "Play Mode" in Unity Editor

Comment: Sorry, English — is not my native language... So, I have Viewport Rect correctly configured for both cameras. Also, that problem did not appear, when I pressing "Play" button in Unity Editor. In both "Game" windows pictures are as planned.